# key props type error in react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am getting an unknown error in my project, the problem is that suddenly when I ran **yarn build** command I got key props type error in all of the components in my project, errors like the picture below:

[image]

error: `Property 'key' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropTypes'.`

```
return (
<Image
  key={Math.random()} // prevent show broken image on loading
  src={loading ? undefined : userID || fileID || type === 'my-pic' ? (isError ? avatar : img) : avatar}
  fallback={
    fullName
      ? fullName
          ?.split(' ')
          .map((s) => s[0])
          .slice(0, 2)
          .join()
      : avatar
  }
  placeholder={<Skeleton.Image active className="w-full h-full" />}
  width={width}
  height={height}
  className={className}
  preview={preview && !isError}
/>
 );
 };
```

i tried closing vscode and reopenning it but didnt work

Comment: Try to remove invalid comment `// prevent show broken image on loading` in JSX you use `{/* ... */}`

Comment: didnt work, it is not just in this lines of code i have this error in all over my project on every key props that i have as i mentioned in the description.